# android :How to show following pattern on empty list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have seen in facebook and flipkart that if list is empty they show a image or whatever which clearly indicates that something is loading 
how to achieve this.Image is not static it look like wave.
[image: sample image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FiftyShadesOf](https://github.com/florent37/FiftyShadesOf) library to archive that effect

Comment: That is what I was searching for. Thanks